# Code bug in java script in web socketing

Tags: javascript, websocket

I created a JavaScript code for sending chat message to web socket but every message it creates a new connection. So each time messages will reply twice. I need a function for handling each action.

The problem is I can't access a method's local variable from another method :(

```
function WebSocketTest()
{
  if ("WebSocket" in window)
  {
     var text=f.input_text.value;
     var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Sobin");
     ws.onopen = function()
     {
        ws.send(text);
     };
     ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
     { 
          var i= evt.data;         
          div = document.createElement('div'); 
          $(div).addClass("b_post").html("<p>"+i+"</p>");              
          $("#content_area").prepend(div);
     };
     ws.onclose = function()
     { 
        alert("Connection is closed..."); 
     };
  }
  else
  {
     // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
     alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this modified Code,with connection Close.

```
require 'em-websocket'

EM.run do

    @clients = []
   EM::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => '8080') do |ws|
    ws.onopen do |handshake|
            @clients << ws
            @name=handshake.path
            @name=@name.sub("/" ,"")
            puts "open";
        end
    ws.onclose do
            ws.send "Closed."//Closing the each connection
            puts "Closed."
            @clients.delete ws
        end

    ws.onmessage do |msg|

                @clients.each do |socket|
                socket.send "#{@name}:"+msg
              end

        end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Create ws as a global variable and make it equal false. Only set ws as a websocket if it equals false. Set ws as false on connection close. Should work ;)

Edit:
If you really don't want to code outside of the function, use the native window object to create global variables inside of the function. You can use if(!ws) as a condition to initialize ws if it either does not exist, equals null, undefined, or false. Set it as a global variable by using window.ws to set it. You will still need to set ws as undefined (probably better than false) on connection closed.

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer .. i  changed code using Jquery

While page loading time also i created a Connection instead of create each time

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Sobin");
```

.and by button clicking time only it will run the sending action
code id

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ("WebSocket" in window)
  {

     var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Sobin");
     ws.onopen = function()
     {
     };
     ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
     { 

          var i= evt.data;         
          div = document.createElement('div'); 
          $(div).attr('id','talkbubble').html("<p>"+i+"</p>");              
          $("#content_area").append(div);
     };
  ws.onclose = function()
     { 
        // websocket is closed.
        alert("Connection is closed..."); 
     };
  }
  else
  {
     // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
     alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
$('#send_button').click(function() {
  var text=f.fname.value;
  ws.send(text);
});
});
```

Comment: That will work as long as the connection isn't closed, otherwise a page refresh is needed. It's easier to handle the initialization of the websocket from within the same function that sends the messages because then you can much more easily implement automatic reconnections and handle disconnections/errors more efficiently. If you don't handle disconnections properly it can completely ruin the stability of whatever you're developing.